# JsonSerializerSettings and Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core

Trying to set JsonOutputFormatter options:

```
var jsonFormatter = (JsonOutputFormatter) options.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f is JsonOutputFormatter);
if (jsonFormatter != null)
{
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

or

```
mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
    {
        jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```

But as soon as I add this, I get:

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'.

I'm using the standard `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json (6.0.0-rc1-final)`

**Edit:** Solved it by installing `Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6` (which downgrades all other references)

Anyone got that already?
Thanks..

Comment: Where you tried to insert the code fragment? What is `mvcBuilder`? Could you include the code of `ConfigureServices` method from `Startup.cs`, which you use? It's correct place to call `AddJsonOptions`.

Comment: This just randomly started happening to me today. Honestly it was working yesterday which really leaves me puzzled.

Answer (score 66):

.Net Core 1.0 RTM comes with CamelCase formatting out-of-the-box. This is a behavior [change](https://wildermuth.com/2016/06/27/Converting-ASP-NET-Core-1-0-RC2-to-RTM-Bits) from RC2. However, if you need to modify it, try this snippet:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        var resolver  = opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
        if (resolver != null)
        {
            var res = resolver as DefaultContractResolver;
            res.NamingStrategy = null;  // <<!-- this removes the camelcasing
        }
    });
```

More information [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/27/Upgrading-to-ASPNET-Core-RTM-from-RC2).

For dotnet core 1.0.1:

```
  services
            .AddMvcCore()
            .AddJsonFormatters(o => o...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out where the automatic camel casing was happening.

Comment: Any idea what this call is in .Net core 1.1?

Comment: @LeviFuller it's the same - `AddJsonOptions`

Comment: I had an already configured SerializeSettings override. Now I have to reproduce everything because I cannot directly set SerializerSettings. There plenty of you should not do that in asp.net core that are not particularly relevant.

Comment: We're moving to asp.net core and decided to use the default setting (camelCase) for all the internal stuff. However, we have a situation that for backwards compatibility to external system we need the output to be PascalCase just for a single controller. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ASP.Net Core and you should use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc":

So replace this:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

by this:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```