# JsonConvert.serializeObject with dataset returning unexpected result

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to convert dataset to JSON in .net core 2.0 and am using the below code to do that

`return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataset, Formatting.Indented))`

and the output I am getting is

`"{\n  \"DataSet.RemotingVersion\": {\n    \"Major\": 2,\n    \"Minor\": 0,\n    \"Build\": -1,\n    \"Revision\": -1,\n    \"MajorRevision\": -1,\n    \"MinorRevision\": -1\n  },\n  \"XmlSchema\": \"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"utf-16\\\"?>\\n<xs:schema id=\\\"dataset\\\" xmlns=\\\"\\\" xmlns:xs=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\\\" xmlns:msdata=\\\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\\\">\\n  <xs:element name=\\\"dataset\\\" msdata:IsDataSet=\\\"true\\\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\\\"true\\\">\\n    <xs:complexType>\\n      <xs:choice minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" maxOccurs=\\\"unbounded\\\">\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"datatable\\\">\\n          <xs:complexType>\\n            <xs:sequence>\\n              <xs:element name=\\\"cvbf\\\" type=\\\"xs:string\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\n            </xs:sequence>\\n          </xs:complexType>\\n        </xs:element>\\n      </xs:choice>\\n    </xs:complexType>\\n  </xs:element>\\n</xs:schema>\",\n  \"XmlDiffGram\": \"<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata=\\\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\\\" xmlns:diffgr=\\\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\\\" />\"\n}"`

Am pretty new to C# development,

- How to convert it into proper JSON?
- and Why is it appearing like this?

Comment: Try: return Ok(dataset), to set your desired serialization method set it globally in the Global.asax or in the WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Does `Newtonsoft.JSON` work with datasets?

Comment: @Prathik Jain it does for my REST server. To some extend... one type of refference between 2 DataSets would not transfer. I'll look up what it was and post it here for info

Comment: What did not work for me when Json Serializing DataSets is: when having 2 DataTables and using DataSet.Relations.Add() on the DataSet the added relation get's lost during serialization/deserialization

Comment: It looks like you may be double-serializing your `DataSet` along the lines of [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182),  [`Ok(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok_System_Object_) takes the object to be serialized, not already-serialized JSON.  It then serializes the object for you.

Comment: OK, aside from the double-serialization there is another issue: The version of Json.NET you are using may not support netstandard20 yet -- and netstandard20 is required for `DataSetConverter`.  See [serializes a DataSet to JSON on dotnet core 2.0 #1409](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1409).  Support was added on [October 1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/ab3315f1d5e57c70203c904be79d8e951bf09794) and so is not in the latest release, [10.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You seem to be double-serializing your `dataset` in the manner described in [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).  First you manually serialize your returned object to a string, then call [`Ok(object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok_System_Object_) which **also** serializes the object passed in (i.e. the JSON string), resulting in a nested serialization.

   The solution is not to do this.   Let the framework serialize your object for you by simply doing `return Ok(dataset);`
2. **Update.** [Json.NET 11.0 Release 1](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2018/02/22/json-net-11-0-release-1-net-standard-2-0-jsonconverters-json-path-and-more) supports .NET Standard 2.0, so serialization for `DataSet` and `DataTable` are now possible in .Net core with this and later versions.  You need to upgrade to this or a subsequent version.

   **Original answer.** Your second problem is that you are trying to serialize a `DataSet` with Json.NET in .Net core using Json.NET [10.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.3) or earlier -- and unfortunately doing so is not yet supported.  As explained in [*Issue #1409: serializes a DataSet to JSON on dotnet core 2.0*](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1409) and [*Issue #1383: .Net core build doesn't include DataTableConverter*](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1383), this release of Json.NET targets netstandard 1.3 while `DataSet` and `DataTable` were introduced in a netstandard 1.5.  Thus this version has no built-on logic to serialize these types in .Net core.

   So, what are your options using this version?  Firstly, Json.NET is licensed under the [MIT License](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/LICENSE.md) so you could copy its versions of [`DataSetConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataSetConverter.cs) and [`DataTableConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs), include them in your project, and add them to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm).  The question  [JsonSerializerSettings and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35772387/3744182) shows how settings can be customized in ASP.NET Core.

   Secondly, you could convert your `DataSet` to a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and return that instead.  For instance, the following extension methods convert any `DataSet` to a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>`, which is serializable by Json.NET:

   ```
   public static class DataSetExtensions
   {
       public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> ToDictionaryList(this DataTable table)
       {
           if (table == null)
               return null;
           return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
               .Select(r => table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c]))
               .ToList();
       }

       public static Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> ToDictionary(this DataSet set)
       {
           if (set == null)
               return null;
           return set.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
               .ToDictionary(t => t.TableName, t => t.ToDictionaryList());
       }
   }
   ```

   Even better, create a strongly-typed model to return.  (If you are also serializing to XML then this is the better solution since `XmlSerializer` does not support serialization of dictionaries.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helpful, I finally fixed my code and it saved me lot of time and research. Especially the links worth million thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As of 25/04/2018. I had exactly same problem. Download latest version of Newtonsoft. I upgraded to 11.0.2. It now works with ASP Core 2. Datasets get converted to JSON.